# Use greater than, less than operations in URL search query

Tags: reactjs, url, query-string

I need to set greater than operator in the search query filter in order to filter the data on a table component within react js page.

what I`m using now but it's not working is the following:

```
http://my-own-site/recentviolations?f_startTime>1656572103987
```

Comment: use another query parameter e.g. `f_startTime_operator=gt` and then parse it and use it accordingly at your backend or use url encoding

Comment: the parameter f_startTime is working with ('=') operator, but how to make it work with greater than operator. and this querystring is not used for backend, but it is to filter and render a table on the react page.

Comment: what I`m really doing is: history.push({pathname: history.pathname, search: 'f_startTime>1656572103987)}) in order to re-render the page with this filter in the querystring. I also Tried different operators symbols (such as 'time1int~currenttime2int', 'time1bigint-currenttime2bigint', f_startTime=gt1656572103987) but all are not working.

Comment: Thanks @Apostolos for your reply, it was the solution for me